# Insert DataGridView contents into Database

Tags: vb.net

I used to dump all data from datagridview into an sql table no problem, until recently for some reason 2 rows that used to be at line 20 & 21, they jumped to line 24&25 ! any idea why sql is doing this ? appreciated
dan

Comment: Without looking at the code it is hard to predict.

Comment: Please provide more info and code example in order to provide you the right suggestions

Comment: show your code .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible in such cases when any changes has done in `Clustered Index` or `Order By` statement of your sql query.

Default sort order has changed of your datagridview column.

if you have made changes in field value where clustered index has created. ie. if you have created clustered index on `Name` field and the value has changed from `Zoe` to `Andy` then that record position will be changed to last to top in that case other records will be shifted to the next row as well.

To determine the why this happens you need both old and new data then compare it which records are added before the line number 20. You can compare that records in excel sheet.

Comment: Hi, my records are always the same and I'm not using any indexing. could of be because I use TRUNCATE table to rewrite all over ?

Comment: I don't think so. But, I need to see how do you fill the table and the gridview. Do you have old backup of your database so, you can compare both database.